# Redirect Website to HTTPS with limited retry?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, https, web

Hi fellow stackoverflowers! I am having a bit of trouble redirecting my website from HTTP to HTTPS using javascript. In the following example, the end goal is to attempt to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS for a maximum of three tries. Once this threshold is exceeded, the website will redirect to a warning page. However, the present code does not redirect properly.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var loc = window.location+'';
if (retry>=3)[
alert('We are sorry, but your client does NOT support SSL(Https) protocol.')
alert("This Website Can Not Be Loaded, Your Browser Is Out Of Date!!!")
window.location.replace("https://example.com/outofdate.html");

if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
document.cookie="retry= + 1";
window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
}
</script>
```

Edit: For reference, this issue is now resolved with the following code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

window.retry = 0;
var loc = window.location+'';
if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
     window.retry +=1;
     window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
}
if(window.retry>=3){
     alert('We are sorry, but your client does NOT support SSL(Https)protocol.');
     alert("This Website Can Not Be Loaded, Your Browser Is Out Of Date!!!");
     window.location.replace("https://example.com/outofdate.html");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Check your code for syntax errors, where is your first if meant to end?
Also you could use window.location.protocol and you need to increment the cookie value `retry` by one instead of setting it to `+ 1`. EDIT: And what clients do you try to "*support*" ? Almost every browser capable of rendering a website supports https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your code for syntax error:

check the syntax where `if(retry>3) [`. The exception **'['** should be **'{'** instead.

You should try `window.retry` to store the variable globally instead of using 'cookie', because some visitors might disable cookie in their browser.

An example should be:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

window.retry = 0;
var loc = window.location+'';
if(window.retry>=3){
     alert('We are sorry, but your client does NOT support SSL(Https)protocol.');
     alert("This Website Can Not Be Loaded, Your Browser Is Out Of Date!!!");
     window.location.replace("https://gamingwiththecrew.com/outofdate.html");
     if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
         window.retry +=1;
         window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
 }

</script>
```

Hope that helps?